# HTML code inside Javascript value code

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string receiving a html code. I'm trying to insert into a table the value, but the result is just the text `<span class='label label-success'>`, not this interpreted.

```
s = "document.instruction_table.column" + cicloAtual +  ".value =<span class='label label-success'> parent.top_frame.instruction_array[0].operator.display_value;</span>";
```

cicloAtual is just a variable with a number.

I think I'm doing something wrong with quotes.

Thanks

Comment: You are assigning a string literal, what do you expect?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? The problem isn't clear, and what's the value of `cicloAtual `?

Comment: I'd like to show the element html.

Comment: What HTML element? There is only a string here, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
    s = "document.instruction_table.column" + cicloAtual +  ".value ="+"<span class='label label-success'>"+parent.top_frame.instruction_array[0].operator.display_value+"</span>";
```